# Google Cloud Sql/GAE latency

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Today I'm experiencing latency in all of my GCP, using GAE and cloud sql. The SQL updates are taking much time than usual, which causes the HTTP requests to be delayed from 1 second to around 1 minute, and it's making the application unusable.

[Google cloud status](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-sql/18004) had an issue in last 24 hours and 'should' be resolved by now, but apparently it's not.

Comment: It seems that you have created a [duplicate thread in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/118331252). Since Issue Tracker is the right place for reporting issues, I recommend to follow up the issue there.

Comment: There is nothing we can do for you as we are not the GCP helpdesk. You had best use the issue tracker as pointed out and delete this question

Comment: Right, we are following up there, thanks.